# Extract part of the content in a Google Sheets cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, text-extraction

I have this content in a cell and I would like to extract just the word **overview** in this case, but could be any work between / and ?. What's the best way for that?

```
/overview?breakdownDimensionId=none&endDate=2019-11-04&startDate=2019-11-04&viewByDimensionId=campaign
```

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "overview")
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "/(.+)\?")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, and without knowing which word is between `/` and `?`:

```
=right(LEFT(A1, SEARCH("~?",A1)-1),len(LEFT(A1, SEARCH("~?",A1)-1))-1)
```